# How do I stop a node.js script after it runs some time

Tags: node.js

My script has a module that wait for a web response and sometimes it just stuck there because of the web environment. I want to automatically stop it after it stucks for 5 min (or 30 seconds) and I don't want to wait the response to timeout. How can I do that?

edit:
The comment from @Yerken is what I need and it works

Comment: The request will automatically stop after the timeout. Do you want to set the timer explicitly?

Comment: what exactly you want to stop?

Comment: @HimaniAgrawal What if I don't want to wait it that long? I kinda just want to wait for like 30 sec and break it.

Comment: @Yerken I want to stop the whole script

Comment: if you want to stop whole script execute `process.exit(1)`

Comment: put this on top of your script `setTimeout(function(){ process.exit(1) }, 30000);` the script will killitself after 30 sec

Comment: You should just set the timeout on your request to the time you want.  There's no reason to restart your server just because a request isn't returning right away.  The server isn't stuck.  It's still fully functional.  So, set the timeout to what you actually want and program your server to handle that appropriately.  No need to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

The article

https://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions

includes a function poll() that may be what you're looking for. If that doesn't work, please explain more about what you want to do. Thanks!